# retrieve session object on jsf view

Tags: session, jsf

I have a `RequestController`(@ManagedBean and @ViewScoped) it is view scoped because we are using some ajax calls.

I have a dataTable with result and each result with a button

```
<p:commandButton action="#{requestController.requestDetail()}" icon="ui-icon-search" title="Detalhes">
     <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{requestController.backing.selectedRequestVO}" value="#{order}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

This method is receiving the selected object of my dataTable and is set on the session, it is working, the problem is that I don't know how to get this session object from my view.

```
public void requestDetail() throws IOException {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("requestDetail",backing.selectedRequestVO);context.getExternalContext().redirect(context.getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath() + "/views/request/detail.html");
    }
```

I need to access it from my view because this object has the request details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just available by the attribute name which you specified yourself.

```
#{requestDetail}
```

Note that this is not the correct approach. You should have another session scoped managed bean which you inject as `@ManagedProperty` in the view scoped managed bean and then set the request detail as its property.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class RequestController {

    @ManagedProperty("#{requestDetail}")
    private RequestDetail requestDetail;

    public String requestDetail() {
        requestDetail.setSelectedRequestVO(backing.getSelectedRequestVO());
        return "/views/request/detail.html?faces-redirect=true";
    }     

    // ...
}
```

with

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class RequestDetail {

    private RequestVO selectedRequestVO;

    // ...
}
```

which you then access as follows

```
#{requestDetail.selectedRequestVO}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please also note that I simplified the redirect approach.

Comment: this line `requestDetail.setSelectedRequestVO(backing.getSelectedRequestVO());` is ok, the object is been returned and set on the `requestDetail` but somehow it is not been set on the session and when I try to get its properties values on my view nothing appears.